# Bypass WordPress and serve static HTML for only the homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a site that I am optimising for speed, the WordPress installation is very plugin heavy and slow but needs to be kept in tact for now.

I am trying to serve a static html file without the site.com**/home** part.

I want to serve the file but keep the url as the root - i.e. **site.com**.

I cannot use template_redirect or any other WordPress functions as I need to bypass  WordPress complete to get the max speed.

Hence why I am using htaccess.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new rewrite rule in your.htaccess file that rewrites all request for yoursite.com to yoursite.com/yourfile.html

Doing so will simply serve yourfile.html to visitors under yoursite.com

Another option is to change your index page using htaccess.

Add this at the top of the . htaccess file in your public_htm

```
DirectoryIndex your_static_htnl_page.html
```

Comment: Great, how do I do that? I can't figure it out. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You most Welcome